# Await a reflow using requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I have an element which I would like to transition from `width: auto` to a fixed width. CSS transitions do not work with `width: auto`, so I require JavaScript to give the element a fixed width before the transition can begin:

```
element.style.width = element.scrollWidth + 'px';
```

I can then set the target width for the element:

```
element.style.width = '420px';
```

Unfortunately most browsers will batch both lines into the same reflow, preventing the transition from working. I have tried using `requestAnimationFrame` to await a reflow, however it seems to get executed immediately. Stacking two `requestAnimationFrame` calls works as expected:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        element.style.width = '420px';
    });
});
```

Why are two calls needed? Why is it useful for `requestAnimationFrame` to run the callback immediately? If I wanted this behaviour I would just do whatever I needed directly.

Comment: Can you provide the code that worked?

Comment: the only thing I can suggest is that the first RAF callback will be called before the next reflow, therefore makes no difference in your case, however, RAF->RAF will be called after the next reflow (and before the reflow after that) and therefore result in what you require - if that makes sense

Comment: you can try `setTimeout(() => {/** your code */}, 0 // or 20 or 70)` this fixes most queue errors or `Promise.resolve().then(. ..)`

Comment: @TachibanaShin I've always found `setTimeout()` to be inconsistent for this sort of thing. I usually use `element.offsetWidth` to force a reflow but I'd rather not rely on a weird side-effect.

Comment: use `promise.resolve()` which is the preferred method of programmers including vue-core

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking why you need to recall `requestAnimationFrame()`.

First, `requestAnimationFrame()` doesn't run come immediately, it runs when it is the next reasonable to do so. For example, if you are on another tab it won't run until you come back.

Also, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) has this note:

> Note: Your callback routine must itself call requestAnimationFrame() again if you want to animate another frame at the next repaint. requestAnimationFrame() is 1 shot.

Unlike `setInterval()`, `requestAnimationFrame()` only schedules code to be run the next time it is reasonable for animation code to be run, so you must recall it to schedule for another animation frame.

This can be more convenient because depending on what is happening, you might want to run a different function next frame, while `setInterval()` only lets you call the same function over and over again. It also makes ending the animation better: all you need to do is not call it again, while ending an interval requires an explicit call to `clearInterval()`.

```js
const element = document.getElementById('box');

element.style.width = element.scrollWidth + 'px';

let width = element.scrollWidth;
function animateBox() {
  width -= 5;
  element.style.width = width + 'px';
  if (width >= 100) requestAnimationFrame(animateBox);
}
requestAnimationFrame(animateBox);
```

```css
#box {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: I think the question was more why does rAF not do what is expected, but rAF callback calling rAF (not continuously, just the one extra) work