Dynamically added SVG animation sometimes not firing
In this example, a ball (SVG circle) is created each time the mouse hovers over the gray square. An animation from the top left to top right is added to the ball and then triggered.
Sometimes, at least in the latest version of Chrome, the ball is created but the animation does not render until the next event trigger. Where am I going wrong?


function anim() {
  const circ = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
  circ.setAttribute("class", "ball");
  circ.setAttribute("cx", 0);
  circ.setAttribute("cy", 0);
  const anim = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "animateTransform");
  anim.setAttribute("attributeName", "transform");
  anim.setAttribute("type", "translate");
  anim.setAttribute("begin", "indefinite");
  anim.setAttribute("from", "0,0");
  anim.setAttribute("to", "300,300");
  anim.setAttribute("dur", "2s");
  anim.setAttribute("repeatCount", "1");
  anim.addEventListener("endEvent", (e) => {
    e.target.parentElement.remove();
  });
  circ.append(anim);
  test.append(circ);
  anim.beginElement();
}
const test = document.querySelector("#test");
test.addEventListener("mouseenter", anim);
#test {
  background-color: lightgray;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.ball {
  fill: black;
  r: 10px;
}
<svg id="test" />




The problems seems to stem from the animation bring triggered before the svg has been repainted.
This snippet puts the adding of the elements to the svg and the begin after the system has had a chance to redraw the changed svg with its new attributes.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #test {
      background-color: lightgray;
      height: 300px;
      width: 300px;
    }
    
    .ball {
      fill: black;
      r: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <svg id="test" />
  <script>
    function anim() {
      const circ = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
      circ.setAttribute("class", "ball");
      circ.setAttribute("cx", 0);
      circ.setAttribute("cy", 0);
      const anim = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "animateTransform");
      anim.setAttribute("attributeName", "transform");
      anim.setAttribute("type", "translate");
      anim.setAttribute("begin", "indefinite");
      anim.setAttribute("from", "0,0");
      anim.setAttribute("to", "300,300");
      anim.setAttribute("dur", "2s");
      anim.setAttribute("repeatCount", "1");
      anim.addEventListener("endEvent", (e) => {
        e.target.parentElement.remove();
      });
      requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        circ.append(anim);
        test.append(circ);
        anim.beginElement();
      });
    }
    const test = document.querySelector("#test");
    test.addEventListener("mouseenter", anim);
  </script>
</body>

</html>




Triggering a reflow (e.g  document.body.offsetWidth;) also works and seems more bullet proof since rAF will fire before the next repaint and possibly before the next recalc too.

@Kaiido that's interesting.  I haven't seen a problem with requestAnimationFrame and thought that it basically had the same reflow effect - means I haven't fully grasped the order of events I guess!

No rAF fires before the next paint and before recalc. Here even a simple setTimeout() also works, so I'm not 100% sure what's happening and I don't have the time to investigate. Still triggering a reflow synchronously is usually the most bullet proof solution since all async solutions might actually seem to work because  something else occurred, and it's not a given that this something else  will always occur. But anyways, if someone could open an issue that would be a good thing.

@Kaiido thanks for the explanation. I’m a bit clearer now and agree a definite forced synchronous reflow should be used, or a double rAF maybe as e.g. discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75527696/await-a-reflow-using-requestanimationframe
